Partial derivatives of nested function $y = f(x_n, f(x_{n-1},f(\dots, f(x_1, x_0))))$
I have the following function: $y = f(e, f(d, f(c, f(a, b))))$. How do I find the partial derivative of y with respect to each of $a, b, c, d, e$? The last one is easy, but I don't know how to do the rest. Can the answer be generalized to $n+1$ variables, for example $x_0,x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$? Of course, this is assuming the partial derivative of the function w.r.t. both its arguments is known. I know I'll need to use the chain rule, which will include the product of successive partial derivatives, but that's it.

I've taken the liberty of swapping $x_0$ and $x_1$ in your header, it will make the answer nicer. In fact the answer would be even easier to write out if you had the variables in reverse order. But surely you can yourself do the cases $n=1,2,3$ and see what the general result must be?

Yes, thank you @ancientmathematician

Recall that $df= {\partial f\over dx} dx+ {\partial f\over dy} dy$
Let $f_n(x_n,...x_1)=f(x_n,f_{n-1}(x_{n-1},...x_1))$
Reporting $f_n$ in $(*)$, as
$df_n=df(x_n, f(x_{n-1},f(..,x_1))$ we get
$df_n= {\partial f\over dx} (x_n, f(x_{n-1},f(..,x_1))dx_n+{\partial f\over dy}(x_n, f(x_{n-1},f(..,x_1)) df_{n-1}
$
We write this as
$df_n = [{\partial f\over dx}]_n dx_n+[{\partial f\over dy}]_n\times df_{n-1}$
So, if you like you can compute this by induction...

Thanks @Thomas, makes sense. I was able to derive $df_{k}$ for an arbitrary $k$ using your method and induction, but I'm not exactly sure how to go from that to $\partial{f_n} / \partial{x_i}$ for an arbitrary $i$. I would appreciate any help!

Just use the formula $df_k= \sum _{i=1}^k {\partial f_k\over \partial x_i} dx_i$. For instance you get ${\partial f_n\over \partial x_n}= [{\partial f \over \partial x}]n$,  then ${\partial f_n\over \partial x{n-1}}= [{\partial f \over \partial y}]n\times [{\partial f \over \partial x}]{n-1}$, etc.

thanks sir. I can get an answer now
